# How to Remove Public/Assets Files From a Branch on Github?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github, heroku

We mistakenly pushed many public/assets files to a branch on github, but we don't want any of those files there (Apparently, if we then push to Heroku, it will cause problems).

OUR QUESTION: Is there a way for us to remove the public/assets files from the github branch without affecting any of the other files?  Our only alternative is to recreate the branch from scratch, which would take days.  So we are trying to avoid that.

We are using Ruby on Rails.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm hoping some people can upvote my question.  Right now, it's negative, and yet, it's a valid question, and the answers below allowed us to solve the problem.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 1. git fetch origin

 - this allow to fetched the changes from the remote repository (origin) but does not merge them into your local branches, an updates your local reference to the remote branches.


 2. git checkout <branch_name>  
 
 -  switches your working directory to the specified branch ex.(<main>). It updates both your working directory and the HEAD to the latest commit of the specified branch.


 3. git pull origin <branch_name>  

 - pulls the latest changes from the remote repository (origin) for the specified branch ex.(<main>). It combines the git fetch and git merge steps into a single command, updating your local branch with the latest changes 
 
 4. git rm -r public/assets 
 -   and this removes the specified directory (public/assets) from your working directory.
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: So if we follow the above commands, it will remove all of the public/assets files from the branch?  We can then commit those changes and repush the changes to github, and it should clean up the branch?

Comment: Any idea how the public/assets files were added to the branch in the first place?  I ask because if we can avoid this happening in the future, that would be very helpfu.

Comment: To anyone in the same situation: we were able to follow the above, and by creating a new branch, and removing the public assets, committing the changes, and pushing that new branch to github, we were able to successfully remove the public/assets files from the pull request.  We are now able to continue working on the branch.

Answer (score 1):

So here are the steps you need to follow

git checkout <your_branch>

> rake assets:clobber
>
> rake assets:precompile

clobber command will remove all public assets.

precompile command will regenerate the new files.

The below command will re-add all new generated files.

> git add public/ -f

now restore all files except any of one via using

> git restore --staged <all_files_except_one>
>
> git commit -m "message"
>
> git push origin <your_branch>

Comment: But why would we want to add the public folder again?  We don't want the public assets to be a part of the branch.